# How to execute a JS function if the parameters do not match?

Tags: javascript

I took this code from internet to modify, to practice JS, though I fail to call the function when the input length is equal 0. So basically I click on the "Add a column" and it opens the console to give the name of the column you want to make, though when the input length as I said is equal to 0, it raises and alert, but it doesn't ask again for the input (I don't know how to call the function so the input console will show up again).

Down below you have the JS code, for the whole code (html, css, js) [click here](https://codepen.io/UStechnology/pen/NWWVQpO).

```
  function Column(name) {
    if (name.length > 0) {
      var self = this; // useful for nested functions

      this.id = randomString();
      this.name = name;
      this.$element = createColumn();

      function createColumn() {
        var $column = $("<div>").addClass("column");
        var $columnTitle = $("<h2>")
          .addClass("column-title")
          .text(self.name);
        var $columnCardList = $("<ul>").addClass("column-card-list");
        var $columnDelete = $("<button>")
          .addClass("btn-delete")
          .text("x");
        var $columnAddCard = $("<button>")
          .addClass("add-card")
          .text("Add a card");

        $columnDelete.click(function() {
          self.removeColumn();
        });
        $columnAddCard.click(function(event) {
          self.addCard(new Card(prompt("Enter the name of the card")));
        });

        $column
          .append($columnTitle)
          .append($columnDelete)
          .append($columnAddCard)
          .append($columnCardList);

        return $column;
      }
    } else if (name.length == 0) {
      alert("please type something");
    } else {
      return;
    }
      }

  Column.prototype = {
    addCard: function(card) {
      this.$element.children("ul").append(card.$element);
    },
    removeColumn: function() {
      this.$element.remove();
    }
  };

  function Card(description) {
    var self = this;

    this.id = randomString();
    this.description = description;
    this.$element = createCard();

    function createCard() {
      var $card = $("<li>").addClass("card");
      var $cardDescription = $("<p>")
        .addClass("card-description")
        .text(self.description);
      var $cardDelete = $("<button>")
        .addClass("btn-delete")
        .text("x");

      $cardDelete.click(function() {
        self.removeCard();
      });

      $card.append($cardDelete).append($cardDescription);
      return $card;
    }
  }

  Card.prototype = {
    removeCard: function() {
      this.$element.remove();
    }
  };

  var board = {
    name: "Kanban Board",
    addColumn: function(column) {
      this.$element.append(column.$element);
      initSortable();
    },
    $element: $("#board .column-container")
  };

  function initSortable() {
    $(".column-card-list")
      .sortable({
        connectWith: ".column-card-list",
        placeholder: "card-placeholder"
      })
      .disableSelection();
  }

  $(".create-column").click(function() {
    var name = prompt("Enter a column name");
    var column = new Column(name);
    board.addColumn(column);
  });

  // ADDING CARDS TO COLUMNS
  todoColumn.addCard(card1);
  doingColumn.addCard(card2);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line:

```
alert("please type something");
```

Add the following:

```
$(".create-column").click();
```

That programmatically "clicks" the Create Column button.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prompt the user to enter column name if length is 0, just add this lines of code to your if-stament:

```
var name = prompt("Enter a column name");   
var column = new Column(name);
board.addColumn(column);.
```

As shown below:

```
else if (name.length == 0) {
      alert("please type something");
      var name = prompt("Enter a column name");
      var column = new Column(name);
      board.addColumn(column);
    } else {
      return;
    }
```

If that was your question, this should be able to fix it.